# I'm really stuck with Python selenium module

Tags: python, selenium

I was making a simple program which enables me to fill out the login form and send email to someone.. and while i'm on it, it just don't go more and stopped at opening some link.

```
# Practice Program!

import requests, os, bs4, webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://google.com'

res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(url)

signinElem = browser.find_element_by_id('gb_70')
signinElem.click()

idElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
idElem.send_keys('not_my_real_id')
idElem.submit()

pwElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')
pwElem.send_keys('not_my_pw')
pwElem.submit()

mailElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('gb_P')
mailElem.click()

composeElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3')
composeElem.click()
```

The code worked well until it hit `pwElem`, which makes me wonder why `signinElem` and `idElem` worked but not `pwElem`??

I happened to stuck with similar situation, where i can pass through some links, but others not. What is wrong with this code?

And i got following Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Cyber/Downloads/WriteMail.py", line 22, in 
>       pwElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')   File "C:\Users\Cyber\Downloads\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 269, in find_element_by_id
>       return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)   File "C:\Users\Cyber\Downloads\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Users\Cyber\Downloads\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Cyber\Downloads\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Passwd"} Stacktrace:
>       at  (file:///C:/Users/Cyber/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpczr__hhf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
>       at  (file:///C:/Users/Cyber/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpczr__hhf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
>       at  (file:///C:/Users/Cyber/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpczr__hhf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>       at  (file:///C:/Users/Cyber/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpczr__hhf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>       at  (file:///C:/Users/Cyber/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpczr__hhf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Comment: show `HTML` for same\

Comment: + when trying to click some links, does browser.find_by_id and browser.find_by_class_name make any difference? Is that why some works and others not?

Comment: @Andersson I tried to parse html code using bs4, but i got []...  soup.select('#Passwd'), soup.select('password-shown'), soup.select('input[Passwd]'), all of them.

Comment: Can you get `HTML` with your browser? Right click on target element -> Show source

Comment: @Andersson  Here's the link! https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vy63JvO9KUE3z1gRH-ZdmXomWkzWS8xbNg7RUGmI3-c/edit?usp=sharing       I was blocked by some vicious military program so i took some time to make it work..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paasword` field is getting visible when you submit the `Email` so you need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until `password` field visible as below :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

-------------

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

idElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Email")))
idElem.send_keys('not_my_real_id')
idElem.submit()


pwElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd")))
pwElem.send_keys('not_my_pw')
pwElem.submit()
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your error message says:.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element

And I see there is a next button on the google login page, right below the Email input box.

So you may click the next button to find the password input box